# How to add a tag with classes in a change function

Tags: jquery, function, button

**Button**:

```
<button id="add-new" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#targetModal"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i> Add New CRR Exclusion</button><br><br>
```

**JQuery:**

```
<script>
    $('#action').on('change',function(){
    var buttonText = $(this).find(':selected').data('buttontext');
    $('#add-new').text(buttonText);
    });  
</script>
```

I have a function that changes the text of a button, but my `<i>` tag disappears when the `<script>` triggers, how do I add my `<i>` tag and it's classes in my function?

I specifically need this to stay with the function triggering `<i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>`

**Default look, icon still there (green button):**
[image: 1]

**When the script triggers, `<i>` is gone:**

[image: 2]

Comment: Can you post an example? Jsfiddle for example. We need to see more code. Are you getting errors in the console

Comment: no errors in the console, i just need certain code to fit in my script to add the tag and its classes

Answer (score 1):

Change your `.lastChild.nodeValue`, not entire text.

Example:

```
$( "#action" ).on("change",function() {
  var buttonText = $(this).find(':selected').data('buttontext');
  $('#add-new').get(0).lastChild.nodeValue = buttonText ;
});
```

Sample Snippet:

```js
$("#action").on("click", function() {
  var buttonText = "  Your New Text  ";
  $('#add-new').get(0).lastChild.nodeValue = buttonText;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='add-new'>
  <i>Your Icon</i> [ old text ]
</div>

<button id='action'> Change text without losing icon tag </button>
```

*Note: If your plugin / FrameWork change your DOM , you need to inspect and catch proper element.*